# Swift NSTimer and shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier issue

Tags: xcode, swift, segue, nstimer

I'm trying to perform a segue after a timer has completed but I can't get the segue to perform.

Here's my code

```
    var timer = NSTimer()

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

func buttonControls() {
    self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image1.png")
    self.timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: "shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

@IBAction func loginButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    buttonControls()
}

@IBAction func signupButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    buttonControls()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image2.png")
}

override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if identifier == "loginSegue" {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSegue", sender: self)
    } else {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("signupSegue", sender: self)
    }

    return true
}
```

I'm new to Swift so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: shouldPeformSegueWithIdentifier doesn't execute once the timer has ran

Comment: Can you tell in detail what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to have it so when you click the 'Login' or 'Signup' button it will change and image in screen before performing a segue (the segue depends on which button has been pressed)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GCD` for that which will delay your segue. Below is the sample code as per your need:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    let dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image2.png")
    }

    @IBAction func loginButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image2.png")
        dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSegue", sender: self)
        })
    }

    @IBAction func signupButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image2.png")
        dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("signupSegue", sender: self)
        })

    }
}
```

[Sample](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=02376609861175677527) project for more Info.

Comment: I'll give that a go. Thanks!

Comment: Sure happy to help you..:)